# Error while creating an SRP target in container using targetcli

Tags: docker, containers, infiniband

I'm trying to setup a container (CentOS 7) that hosts an SRP target using LIO. As far as I can tell the container has the correct access to the bits on the host (CoreOS 4.7.3) because I'm able to start `targetcli` without error and have been successful in creating a new block device. The next command I'm trying to issue is `/srpt create wwn=<Infiniband WWPN>` but I get the error

```
Could not create SRPTFabricModule in configFS
```

The command that I've used to run my container is

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --cap-add=ALL \
--tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \
-v /sys/kernel/config:/sys/kernel/config \
-v /dev/infiniband:/dev/infiniband hpc/san /bin/bash
```

This has been everything that I could find is required to use an InfiniBand interface and ZFS in a container. I did find an comment in an issue on the zfsonlinux repo in Github that said to `rmmod target_core_mod` and then `modprobe` and mount `configfs`, but that's for the case where `target_core_mod` have been loaded without it, and that's not what I have.

```
lsmod | grep configfs
configfs               32768  4 rdma_cm,iscsi_target_mod,target_core_mod

mount | grep configfs
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
```

I'm hoping that this is some permissions or access problem between the container and the host because that would probably be easiest to resolve.